# Best practices for a microstrategy workflow

Tags: microstrategy

we are a team of 5 people working with microstrategy. We share every role, but we have no worklfow.

Everybody may build or change attributes and change the schema. This leads often to reports not working. Furthermore, there is no "good" documentation. We tried to establish a documentation with sharepoint, but there we also had no workflow.

Originally, we had an old project where for every report all the attributes where constructed newly. So we did not reuse any existing schema object.

Hence, we started a new project. We realized that due to lack of understanding and lack of workflow we make and made a lot of mistakes. We feel that we understand things better slowly (parent child), but the workflow is still horrible.

We have a development project and a lice project, but with the way we are working now, we have a lot of problems. Particularly, the missing version control system is killing us. We perform changes and forget what we did. Hence, we have to use backups, destroying useful work on a given day

So what are best practices to:
 * deploy new attributes, facts and reports
 * ensure that old reports work after constructing new attributes and facts
 * improve documentation
 * attributes defined on fact tables and parent-child relationships

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MicroStrategy development in a team environment, deploying from development to live, can be very challenging. As you rightly point out, the lack of version control, and unknown interdependencies between objects can cause untold problems. There's no one right answer to this question, but I would suggest the following:

Use all the tools provided by MicroStrategy. When you're deploying from one project to another, don't just drag and drop in Object Manager, create a package. When you deploy that package, make sure you choose to create an undo package, so you can rollback changes if you encounter any problems.

On that note, try to catch these problems in advance. Running Integrity Manager before and after a deployment, even if it's just to generate SQL for the reports, will point out if you've broken anything. On that note:

Create a third environment/project. Call this test/release control, whatever you prefer. Here you can test packages created in Object Manager, to ensure that they have the desired effect, and don't break anything. In effect, this is a dry run for your deployment to live. This environment should be regularly refreshed from live (via project duplication), to make sure it doesn't get in an unexpected state (as the result of a broken Object Manager package import for example).

Over and above that, I can only offer organisational advice. It's not uncommon for one person to take responsibility for schema objects (i.e. facts, attributes, transformations) so that developers don't undo each other's changes. If you have a large project, these objects could be split into functional areas, and individuals assigned.

Documentation is always tricky, but I like to put as much as possible into the object descriptions. This has the advantage of being visible in the Web interface (via tooltips), and included in the automated project documentation, should you choose to generate that. There is obviously the change log functionality for each object, but in my experience, those logs are soon not completed by developers, as saving happens too frequently. Still, if you can get people to populate that, you'd have a head start on understanding the change in your project.

**To summarise:**

- Use Object Manager packages to deploy changes
- Test changes with Integrity Manager, to catch any issues as early as possible
- Use a release control project/environment, so you're not catching issues in your production environment
- Assign responsibility for schema objects to a specific person or persons where possible.

Comment: thanks for the hints. I'll try to enfore more discipline here. I hope, i can convince the others at least to use packages :)